# Cassandra CQL query giving error with ORDER BY ASC and LIMIT

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax-enterprise

I have created a Cassandra table with below configuration :

```
CREATE TABLE "ABC" (
    subsector text,
    marketcapital decimal,
    id text,
    PRIMARY KEY (subsector, marketcapital, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ( marketcapital DESC, id ASC )
```

CQL query giving error on running in Datastax dev center :

```
select * from "ABC" where subsector='10010' and marketcapital > 50717820.457485 ORDER BY marketcapital ASC  LIMIT 3
```

On executing above query i get below error:

[image]

Seems error with ORDER BY ASC with LIMIT keyword.

Comment: I am able to resolve the issue by not giving any ORDER BY value eg below... but not sure why this works but not the above query.                                                                                           select * from "EquitiesBySubsector" where subsector='10010' and marketcapital > 50717820.457485 ORDER BY marketcapital LIMIT 3

Comment: Hmmm, the query in the error message looks differently. Can you check that query in the `cqlsh`?

Comment: It is definitely a valid CQL query.  I'm noticing how the error message truncates the space between `marketcapital` and LIMIT.  It looks like a query parsing bug in Dev Center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with Datastax Dev Center, as when I run the same query with cqlsh works fine.

Most probable reason is Dev center is using some old version of CQL spec, due to this error occurred.